# Excel - combining two pivot tables like SQL left outer join

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Are we able to combine two pivot tables just like SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN?

For example I have two tables. table1 looks like below.

[image: table1]

And table2 looks like below.

[image: table2]

Now I want to make a pivot of both tables and combine them into one pivot table. However, I have no clue how to do that.

The pivot tables from both tables look like below.
[image: pivottable from table1]

[image: pivottable from table2]

What I am expecting looks like below.

[image: pivottable result]

I know how to link the filter, using the slicer and connection. However, I have no clue how to LEFT OUTER JOIN these two pivot tables altogether. Is it possible to achieve in Excel?

Thanks for any advice and responses.

Comment: Why not create a third table that combines the two?

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but then the filter is not working as expected.

Comment: Ok, how about creating extra fields that concatenate param_3 and the other param_3. You can then filter the new field.

Comment: @arnold Did my suggestion re PowerPivot help solve your issue? Or don't you have the required Excel version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one of the versions of Excel listed at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Where-is-Power-Pivot-aa64e217-4b6e-410b-8337-20b87e1c2a4b then you can use PowerPivot and the DataModel to join your two tables on a key column. Then you can combine them in one PivotTable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jefrey. Sorry slow response. Took sometime for me to completely understand the power pivot. Quite a learning curve, however, it is really convenient once I finish the tutorial! Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool! Enjoy the trip.